# iMac mid 2011 Extremely slow after new SSD

Tags: mac, ssd, performance

I have put a few SSD's in this iMac and it has run really fast.
I have an SSD and HDD installed, and I install the OS on the SSD.
I recently replaced the 1TB SSD with a 2TB SSD for extra storage and now it is so slow. Blackmagicdesign Disk Speed Test reports write speed of 5.9MB/s (not GB/s). it's painful. The HDD is reporting over 50MB/s from the disk speed test.

Could the SSD be faulty? Is it because it is a 2TB SSD?
The new SSD is mounted as an APFS volume and the HDD is SATA Internal Physical Volume.
Is there anything else I should check?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would normally suggest to return the SSD. But as this is a [Crucial SSD](https://www.crucial.com/ssd/bx500/ct2000bx500ssd1), better get in touch with their Support.

Comment: What does the System Information application show as the Negotiated Link Speed?

Comment: Negotiated Link Speed is 6 Gigabit. I have added a screengrab of that above